# Display currently set image in Django ImageField instead of URL

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django ModelForm with an ImageField. When the user edits the model the Image Field displays:

[image]

Is there a way to use the URL presented beside "Currently" to display/render the set image instead of the actual URL.

Comment: Can you add you model structure ?

Comment: The entire class?

Comment: yes, it's in custom template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to get the image I actually just used an image tag in the template, however instead of using `{{ form.image.url }}` you can use `{{ form.image.value}}` and use an if statement to display some default image if it is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Add the image tag and specify that URL as the "src" of the image.

How I do it in my applications is that I keep the images in a separate media folder but you are using a static folder, so you can use it like :

```
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}{{form.image.url}}">
```

Since I don't know where that image is coming from, I can't specify how to you make the 'src' tag dynamic.

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how to get that URL from the ModelForm. The field is called "image" in the ModelForm, so my thoughts were I could pull that in the template using `{{ form.image.url }}` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You are saving the image in the package_images folder right? Your tag becomes <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}{{form.image.url}}">

Comment: Please check if you have the STATIC_URL defined in the django.settings.py file

Comment: Yea I am, however I used this to my success: `<img src="/{{ form.image.value }}">`